# Onclick check if the input field is empty then change the text onclick to password

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="input_discount" id="discountCode" placeholder="ENTER YOUR TEXT">

<button type="button" class="btn apply_btn" id="changeType" required/>APPLY</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#changeType').click(function(){
    $('#discountCode').attr('type','password');
});
```

The code is working fine. But when I enter the text in the input field and click on apply button, then it converts the input type to password. But when I directly click on apply button and then write inside the input field it shows password format. Can anybody tell me how to prevent this if input field is empty and user clicks on apply button the input type remains focused and should be in text format and after filling the details it should convert to password format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why your code was not working.**

When there was nothing entered, as per your code it was converting the type to text.

**Solution I applied**

While the button is clicked, check if textbox is empty or not.

> Note: I am considering `space` as a valid character in the input box, because it can be used for password. If you want to eliminate `space` you can use
>   `$('#discountCode').val().trim().length`

**Working Demo**

```js
$('#changeType').click(function(e) {
  if ($('#discountCode').val().length) {
    $('#discountCode').attr('type', 'password');
  } else {
    $('#discountCode').attr('type', 'text');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input_discount" id="discountCode" placeholder="ENTER YOUR TEXT">

<button type="button" class="btn apply_btn" id="changeType" required/>APPLY</button>
```

Comment: @PreetyAngel Always glad to hear that `:)`